# Generating script in SSMS 2016 RC for Azure database omits default values

Tags: sql-server, azure, constraints, ssms

I have migrated my local SQL Server database to Azure using the built-in migration tool in SSMS 2016 release candidate. Apart from a number of failed conversions of stored procedures which use features disallowed in Azure, it looks OK.

I have now generated scripts of the schema from both the local and the Azure versions of the database, using the same scripting options, so that I can compare the scripts of the databases and identify any differences or other missing items.

My problem is that the script generated from Azure does not include the default value constraints on columns. Looking at the table definitions directly in SSMS shows that the default values have correctly been set.

Can anyone help me to get the SSMS script generator to add the default value constraints into the generated script?

This is an example script from the local database:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
CREATE TABLE [xOrgBusinessType](
    [OrgID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BusTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CRD] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_xOrgBusinessType_CRD]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()),
    [CRDByID] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_xOrgBusinessType_CRDByID]  DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_xOrgBusinessType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrgID] ASC,
    [BusTypeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

and the equivalent script from the Azure database

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
CREATE TABLE [xOrgBusinessType](
    [OrgID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BusTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CRD] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CRDByID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_xOrgBusinessType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrgID] ASC,
    [BusTypeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my own question. I made a mistake when comparing the scripts from the two databases. The local database script was generated by SSMS 2014, whereas the Azure database script was generated by SSMS 2016, and the two versions treat CONSTRAINT .. DEFAULT .. differently.

In the case of 2014, the constraint is scripted with the column definition. In the case of 2016, all the constraints are scripted in a later block, as ALTER TABLE .. ADD CONSTRAINT .. commands.

Although my question is answered, the SSMS 2016 approach seems somewhat bizarre. In the case of the script above, the CREATE TABLE script is around line 2500, while the ALTER TABLE script is at line 13100. Further, I had set the option to "Include descriptive headers", but the ALTER TABLE statements are not preceded by an object header, even though that part of the script defines a constraint object.

I wonder why the ALTER TABLE statements are so far removed from the table definitions. There seems to be no reason not to include them right after to the CREATE TABLE script.